# Installing Fedora: does it matter what I make the hostname?

Tags: linux, fedora, setup

I'm in the process of setting up a Fedora machine just for use on my in-house lan (not exposed to the internet.)

This seems like a slightly stupid question, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere: does it matter what I make the hostname?

The default is "localhost.localdomain" - should I leave that, change it to something meaningful, or just set it to something like "fedoramachine" or "bilbo"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It helps to set [*some* name](https://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/06/set-your-hostname-in-linux/).
But, from a networking standpoint, the name does not matter.
[Some](https://jblevins.org/log/hostname) other [notes](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/farslayer-214143/setting-the-linux-hostname-1648/) that might be useful.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks, nik. That's what I *thought*, but Fedora's prompt caused me to lose confidence.